# jquery-chosen failed to select multiple values for select tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

using jquery chosen for select tag.

Problem is when im trying this working fine

```
$('#pc_sel_email').val(["1", "4", "2"]).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

When im replacing "1", "4", "2" with a dynamic generated value is not showing any selected values

```
//allData - 1#@test#@9#@startstartart#@startstartstarartstartstart#@1#@1,2,3
var data= allData.split("#@");
var emaiLIDS= data[6].split(",");
var emailIDList="";
for( var i=0; i<emaiLIDS.length; i++){
    emailIDList+='"'+emaiLIDS[i]+'"';
    if(i!=emaiLIDS.length-1){
       emailIDList+=', ';
    }
}

jQuery('#pc_sel_email').val([ emailIDList ]).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Then nothing is selected. Please help am i missing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do the whole `emailIDList` thing. Just pass `emaiLIDS` directly like this:

```
var allData = "1#@test#@9#@startstartart#@startstartstarartstartstart#@1#@1,2,3";
var data= allData.split("#@");
var emaiLIDS= data[6].split(",");
$('#pc_sel_email').val(emaiLIDS);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4xEdd/

Comment: Thanks working fine, updated with this line jQuery('#pc_sel_email').val(emaiLIDS).trigger("liszt:updated");